# couchdb exited: app_would_not_start,public_key

Tags: linux, erlang, couchdb

I'm getting this CouchDB error, and I literally cannot find documentation for it anywhere! It looks like it might be an ssh problem, but I don't quite see how. Mainly I am just curious if anyone knows about this error or how to diagnose it?

```
=INFO REPORT==== 10-Aug-2013::12:37:17 ===
application: couch
exited: {{app_would_not_start,public_key},
         {couch_app,start,
                    [normal,
                     ["/home/me/etc/couchdb/default.ini",
                      "/home/me/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]}}
type: temporary
```

couchdb.stderr shows this output right away when trying to run it:

```
heart_beat_kill_pid = 1028162
heart_beat_timeout = 11

heart_beat_kill_pid = 1046062
heart_beat_timeout = 11

heart_beat_kill_pid = 5462
heart_beat_timeout = 11

heart_beat_kill_pid = 354270
heart_beat_timeout = 11
```

CouchDB version 1.1.1
Erlang R15B
GNU/Linux

I had CouchDB working, but I ran into some problems where it would intermittently shut down every couple of hours/days, so I tried to upgrade Erlang to newest since the couchdb.stderr file seemed to be pointing the finger at Erlang. After upgrading, continually got this. So I did wget/make/make install over the new install of erlang to the version that I knew worked, but still can no longer get it to start. Just crashes right away

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like public_key isn't started, open up your erlang shell and type this: `application:load(public_key).` it should return `ok`

Comment: Ultimately, all of this came down to issues where when I tried to upgrade Erlang and CouchDB on a CentOS Linux server, there were some leftover stragglers from Erlang because they do not have a "make uninstall" - these straggler files were left over either from Erlang or CouchDB. Manually removing anything that resembled either one of them and doing a make and make install from the source ultimately worked